# Issue with response of HTTPRequest

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest

So, I'm trying to get byte from an HTTP request.
I did `responseType = arraybuffer` and I would like to receive this array.

```
   this._xhr.onreadystatechange = function()
         {
            if($this._xhr.readyState == 4)
            {
                if($this.successStatus.contains($this._xhr.status) && typeof($this.succeed) == "function")
                {
                    console.warn($this._xhr); //LOG 1
                    console.warn($this._xhr.response); // LOG 2
                    debugger;
                    if($this.responseType == "" || $this.responseType == "text")
                       $this.succeed($this.raw ? $this._xhr.responseText : JSON.parse($this._xhr.responseText));
                    else
                        $this.succeed($this._xhr.response);
                }
            }
        }
```

So I use this code and I would like to call the function this.succeed giving the parameters I want

```
$this.succeed($this._xhr.response);
```

The problem is, on the console I have that

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You're making an assumption about what the `console.warn()` output is telling you. I don't think it's actually true that the buffer is empty.

Comment: Ye I think so too. hx